# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

I'm trying to decode the string but getting an error, and here is part of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rsa

def constLenBin(s):
    binary = "0"*(8-(len(bin(s))-2))+bin(s).replace('0b','')
    return binary

data = 'apple'
(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(1024)
crypto = rsa.encrypt(data.encode(), pubkey)
crypto = crypto.decode()
binary = ''.join(map(constLenBin,bytearray(crypto, 'utf-8')))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "stdin", line 1, in
>   module
>  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99
>   in position 0: 
> invalid start byte

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: But the error is correct, \x99 isn't valid UTF8, why do you think it is?

Comment: It was a complex problem. I was using rsa module

Comment: To be able to decode, you need to know what the encoding it is. And it's impossible to guess from just a single byte.

Comment: I'm using rsa module. And I want to encrypt str by using rsa.encrypt(), it return bytes type. Then I hide it into a image. However, it must be str before.

Comment: Ah. You cannot turn that into a Unicode string, as it really is a sequence of bytes, it's not an encoded version of some Unicode string. That should be no problem as images are also not strings, just bytes. Why do you need a str?

Comment: Yes, maybe I need to rewrite the def

Comment: It works. I used bytes to write the information. Thanks you!

Answer (score 4):

As Remco notes, `\x99` is not valid UTF8 byte. You need to specify encoding name, for example:

```
a = b'\x99'; a = a.decode('latin-1'); print(a)
```

Comment: But the outcome depends entirely on the encoding you choose. In Latin-1 \x99 seems to be undefined, maybe it was cp1252 where it's `™`. But pick another encoding and it's something different.

Comment: Yes. I have wrote latin-1 just for example. Probably it was cp1252.

Comment: @Dmitry: How to check whether the byte is valid `UTF-8` or not ?